# Problem with Wikipedia API module in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem. I'm using the `wikipedia` API for Python.
So I was trying to create a very simple program to research into Wikipedia through Python:

```
import wikipedia as wiki

while True:
    try:
        search = input("Search something: ")
        break
    except:
        print("No results were found")

# I want to save the text in a file, but section by section, with a for loop in page.sections

with open(f"{page.name}.txt", "a") as file:
    for sect in page.sections:
        file.write(sect + "\n")
        file.write(page.section(sect))
```

But when I execute it, I get this error:
`TypeError: a 'str' object is required, not 'NoneType'`
It should return a string, not a NoneType object. What should I do?

Comment: is the variable page defined?

Comment: Consider adding the entire traceback instead of just the error message. Also, it *should* return a string? Are you not sure if it returns a string of not. Consider checking the documentation for the library you're using

Comment: @WasiMaster it RETURNS a string. If I use it in another program in the SAME context it just returns a string.